# graphviz directed graph with parents at top

Tags: graphviz

This directed graph

```
digraph G {
    Semigroup
    Monoid -> Semigroup
    Band -> Semigroup
}
```

renders with `dot` as

[image]

but I really want the `Semigroup` to be at the top. I have a much bigger example than this, so hacks like using `rank` aren't going to work. The general theme is that I want the arrows to point upwards instead of downwards.

I tried using the `-y` parameter, but it makes no difference.

If I could use `<-` in my file getting the top/down order correct, I'd need a way to reverse the drawing of the arrow.

Answer (score 3):

You add this to the graph

```
    rankdir = BT;
```